# Strange history (goBack) behavior on react navigation v6 for tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

i make a little snak for explain my purpose [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@bug00/getting-started-%7C-react-navigation)

In this (dirty) example i have 4 screen : feed, profile, settings and toto. When i navigate there are only 2 routes that are remain in history : the first (feed) and the last (currently route). The last route overwrite the n-1 route.

An example : try to navigate from feed > profile > settings and go back : we go to feed, but i want return on profile screen.

In my app i had a more complex architecture : stack > tab > stack (tab.screen) > screen and i had the same issue.

I suspect a bug in react navigation cause i don't understand why state `state.routes[0].state?.history` not remain all passed route (Look the LOGS console). Or there somethings i misunderstand ?

If anyone have an idea :)

Thanks

Edit:
On v5 this works like a charm : https://snack.expo.dev/@bug00/5b964c
state...history keep the track of visited routes.

Also notes that on V6 console.log is called more more times at each navigation, on V5 there is one console.log at each navigation